# vim: execute the rest of the line after the cursor as a vim command

Tags: vim

I sometimes find myself writing text where part of the file is generated by an external program. Consider for example a C source file containing

```
/*
 * To regenerate the following data, place the cursor at the beginning
 * of the next line after this comment, then run
 *   ma:r!find /foo -name '*.in' | xargs whatever | some complicated processing
 * and merge the result with
 *   'a!}sort -u
 */
some
generated
stuff
here
```

I end up using the mouse to select the first command (`ma:...`), paste & run it, wait for the command to finish, the select `'a!}sort -u` and paste & run it. That's inelegant because it's only semiautomatic when I think it could be fully automatic. I read the vim online help for `:execute` and friends but it looks like that's not doing what I want. I'm thinking more along filling a vim register with the proper command(s), then execute the register contents. The online `:help registers` did not give a clue so far.

Ideally, the new comment would say something like

```
/*
 * To regenerate the following data, place the cursor on the 'j' on the
 * next line in this comment, then execute it with <SHORT-MAGIC-VIM-INCANTATION>
 *   jjma:r!find /foo -name '*.in' | xargs whatever | ...<CR>'a!}sort -u<CR>
 */
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make it handle Ex commands, not normal mode commands (like `ma` in your example); it is easy to execute the latter via `:normal ma`, but feeding Ex commands into normal mode has escaping problems (like, how do you encode the <kbd>Enter</kbd> that has to conclude the Ex command?)

Here's a custom command:

```
command! -bar -range ExecuteFromCursor execute 'normal! "zy$' | @z
```

And here's a mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>e "zy$:@z<CR>
```

Comment: Oh aha. `:@z` for register is way easier (to describe as well) than `^R` register 'completion'. +1

Comment: The `nnoremap` as is doesn't move the cursor to the appropriate line. A little modification fixes this: `"zy$2j:@z<CR>`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Ingo's method of executing the register is easier than mine (`@"` instead of `<^R>"`).

*The advantage with my approach would be that you have a chance to interactively edit the command line just like any other, before pressing Enter to execute.*

I'd do

```
y$:<^R>"
```

- `y$`  *yank to end of line*
- `:` *start command mode*
- <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>    *insert yanked text*

Press Enter, profit.

---

I used to have something similar mapped. But I got lazy and often just do <kbd>Y</kbd> and edit the command line. On windows, I find <kbd>Shift-Insert</kbd> on the vim command line a bit smoother, so I'd then use <kbd>"+Y</kbd> to copy to the windows clipboard. But I digress

Comment: Could it be that the C-v is wrong here? When I do `y$:<C-R>"` the yanked text is pasted to command mode.

Comment: @Jens You're right. I was confusing making a mapping with 'live' execution. Fixed it. Thanks for the heads-up